# How can I dynamically load values from .env in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile target that looks like this:

```
env-%:
    @echo "Getting ${*} env"
    cat .env-common > .env
    @echo >> .env
    cat .env-${*} >> .env
    @echo >> .env
    cat .env

    echo "Loading .env contents into shell"
    source .env

    echo ${SOMETHING_FROM_COMMON}
    echo ${SOMETHING_FROM_DEV}
```

Other targets that then expect  `SOMETHING_FROM_DEV` to be in the environment, eg:

```
something-else-%: .env-%
    echo ${SOMETHING_FROM_DEV} # Actual step is a docker build, but thats irrelevant here I think.
```

The idea is that I can call it like `$ make something-else-dev` and it will run the prerequesit task of `env-dev`, which concats two environment files to create a `.env` file. Then it needs to load everything in `.env` into the shell, finishing the prerequisite steps. Finally, `something-else` runs and the echo (or whatever that recipe contains) has the values for use.

The .env-common file looks like this:

```
# Common variables
SOMETHING_FROM_COMMON=hello
```

The .env-dev file looks like this:

```
# Dev specific variables
SOMETHING_FROM_DEV=hello-from-dev
```

Trying `include` as above yields this:

```
echo "Loading .env contents into shell"
Loading .env contents into shell
include .env
make: include: No such file or directory
make: *** [env-dev] Error 1
```

Using `eval` brings in the file too early, I think at first-use rather than at runtime in the target. `source` seems to not work as I'd expect, but I suspect I'm not understanding it right either.

Perhaps theres a way to call out to bash to load these into the environment?

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/shawnbot/6170473) is close but I ideally want to use the `$$SECRET_KEY` from the example between targets.

Ideally comments (prepended with `#` would be supported in the .env file too, but it's not a deal breaker.

Any ideas / thoughts welcome.

Comment: The lines inside a recipe are executed by the shell, not directly by `make`. You want to put the `include` outside the recipe, and probably by common convention call the file something like `includes.mk`

Comment: Or if you only want the shell to read the file, the syntax for that is `. .env` but the effects of that will be lost immediately, unless you specify `.ONESHELL` or refactor your recipe to run a single shell instance.  You also need to double the dollar signs to prevent `make` from eating them.

Comment: @tripleee If i put it outside the recipe, I can't do this ordering of steps right?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "this ordering of steps". Make knows that if it `include`s a file, its own understanding will depend on that, so it arranges things accordingly (but you can still paint yourself into a corner if you create circular dependencies etc).

Comment: Your question remains unclear; I have now proposed three different solutions (two comments, and one answer), but it is not at all clear which of these - if any - solves your problem. Please [edit] to elaborate on what you hope your code should do. Code which doesn't do what you want is a terrible way to communicate what you do want.

Comment: @tripleee My apologies for the lack of clarity – definitely not my intention. I appreciate your time so far. I have now edited my question with more verbosity and hopefully that makes the task clear :)

Comment: So I think my answer is actually a better way to do what you are asking. You could improve on the `.env` files by writing them in Make syntax, but if they need to be `sh`-compatible, that works too (just that the assignments will be re-evaluated by `make` every time you refer to one of those variables).

Comment: "this ordering of steps" refers to 
1. Make the .env file
2. read the .env file

using `-include .env` reads it once, first,  as far as I can tell, and doesn't seem to re-read it if it changes?

Comment: @tripleee Okay, I think I'll rethink the approach. I'm probably approaching this too much like a JS dev rather than a makefile thinker and getting myself confused too much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should simply use a different facility instead.

```
include .env-common
include .env-${ENV}
```

Now, `make ENV=dev` will include `.env-common` and `.env-dev`.

Maybe make the second conditional and only do it if `ENV` is actually set, or specify a default for `ENV`.